# What is the correct way to stream my own types in yaml-cpp?

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I'm  confused on using YAML-CPP with my own types.  The documentation I can find seems to list two different ways to stream them.

First the "How To Emit YAML" page says just [overload `operator <<` for YAML::Emitter](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/How-To-Emit-YAML).    Obviously this is just for output.   But I can't find any mention about writing some sort of equivalent `operator >>` overloads for the `YAML::Parser`

Meanwhile [the "Tutorial" page](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial) says

> To use yaml-cpp with your own data types, you need to specialize
> the YAML::convert<> template class.

This approach it lists has me writing both an `encode` and `decode` function in my convert specialization.

I'm using the current, 0.6 release.  Is one of these the "old" way and one the "new" way or do I need to do both?  And if I need to do both, how do these two work together?  Because it makes no sense to me that the convert-specialization thing would require both an `encode`/`decode` function when `operator <<` should take care of one of them

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, I only see this post now.

As a partial answer, what I did for the operator<< is the following:

```
template <typename T_>
YAML::Emitter& operator<<(YAML::Emitter& out, const T_& rhs) {
  out << convert<T_>::encode(rhs);
  return out;
}
```

This way you have only a single operator<< for all your custom types, which simply uses the implementation you already created in your custom YAML convert specialization.

You can do something similar for the operator>> I suppose, but I haven't ever had the need for it, given that with your custom YAML convert specialization, you can already write something as simple as:

```
my_custom_type_instance = yaml_node.as<MyCustomType>();
```